# Sum of kth binomial coefficient but starting at index 1.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I want to know what is the sum $\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{1+k} + \binom{n}{1+2k} +...$. The answer for when it starts at 0 can be derived with roots of unity and simply adding, and I suspect the same here, except we need to multiply by coefficients to get the right terms to cancel, and finding those coefficients seems horrible in general. I didn't even feel like doing it for k=3. Is there a simple way to find this sum?

Comment: It's just 1, but my series starts at 1 not 0

Comment: I remember reading in enumerative combinatorics by aigner that there is no closed form for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega_j = \exp(2 \pi i j/k)$ be the $k$'th roots of unity.  We have
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \omega_j^m = \cases{k & if $k | m$\cr 0 & otherwise}$$
Thus
$$ \sum_{m \equiv 1 \mod k} {n \choose m} 
= \dfrac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \sum_{m=0}^n  {n \choose m}\omega_j^{m-1} = 
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{(1 + \omega_j)^n \overline{\omega_j}}{k}$$
For example, for $k=3$, noting that $1 + \omega_j = -\overline{\omega_j}$ for the non-real roots, you get $$ \dfrac{2^n+2 \cos( (n-2) \pi/3 )}{3}$$
(OEIS sequence [A024494](https://oeis.org/A024494)).

EDIT: The generating function of your sequence is

$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{(1+\omega_j)^n \overline{\omega_j} x^n}{k} = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{(\overline{\omega_j}+1) x}{k(1 - (1+\omega_j) x)}$$

Comment: Can you explain that double summation step please?

Comment: Oh wait never mind. You decomposed k into the sum of roots of unity.